# Python syntax error "def"

Tags: coding-style, python-2.7

I am trying to compile this piece of Python code-

```
def isPrime ( n ):
    if n < 2 :
        return false
    for x in range(2,n):
        if (n % x)==0:
            return false
    return true

def nthPrime ( n ):
    y = 0
    z = 1
    while y< n:
        z+=1
        if isPrime( z ):
            y+=1
    return z
```

But I am having this error in line 9 on "def"

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Is how the code looks here exactly as it looks on your screen? Your indenting is messed up.

Comment: There is no syntax error in the code you edited to. `false` and `true` will presumably raise NameError when you call the functions, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a fixed up version of your code, with proper indenting and using `True` and `False`, not `true` and `false`:

```
def isPrime( n ):
    if n < 2 :
        return False
    for x in range(2,n):
        if (n % x)==0:
            return False
    return True

def nthPrime( n ):
    y = 0
    z = 1
    while y < n:
        z+=1
        if isPrime( z ):
            y+=1
    return z
```

---

And here's a version of your code that conforms more to the [PEP 8 style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for python:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if (n % x) == 0:
            return False
    return True


def nthPrime(n):
    y = 0
    z = 1
    while y < n:
        z += 1
        if isPrime(z):
            y += 1
    return z
```

I prefer the second piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for the correction but one more thing, this code still shows that error on Python shell but in Pycharm it works just fine.

Comment: When I run `print nthPrime(10)` after the second piece of code, I get `29`. Do you still get a syntax error when you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent python, like this:

```
def nthPrime(n):
    y = 0
```

Not like this:

```
def nthPrime(n):
y = 0
```

Read more about it [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html)

Comment: Actually I did that, but when I posted the code here it became like this. Anyway, the code is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is obviously a super noob error (as I am right now) but the issue was that the error was NOT on line 9 (or whatever your def tag is) but in fact the line before.

Mine was a missing end bracket. - This guys case was like that `false` should have been `False`